# MS Access Bound Object Frame

Tags: ms-access

I made an access bound object frame that has a datasheet form in it. The actual form has more than one row but the one in the bound object shows only one. Any ideas?

Comment: Do you mean a SubForm control?  A Subform control is distinct and different than a "bound object frame".  If it really is a "bound object frame", that is a non-standard way of showing a datasheet.

Comment: As for a Subform, it could 1) have its Filter property set, or 2) have `Link Master Fields` and `Link Child Fields` properties set which filter the form based on the parent form.

Comment: Thanks but the frame is now linked to a qty based on the same table and I'm getting the same result @CPerkins

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Solved it. Should have been a subform instead of an unbound object frame.